# Krom Kayle Headphones - Issues Installing Driver

Tags: drivers, troubleshooting, headphones

Purchased the Krom Kayle headphones for WFH purposes. I am unable to install driver in order to use them. I've gone to Krom site to download but receive an error message - "This file has no associated application to carry out this action".

I'm using my Lenovo laptop running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's a .rar file. A compressed file format, a bit like a .zip but not identical.

You need something that knows how to unpack it. Windows can't do it natively.

This was the first I found on the Windows Store. there are a myriad others.
[RAR Opener](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/rar-opener/9wzdncrdhktr?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: https://www.7-zip.org/ will also open a RAR archive.

Comment: Thanks for this information! I tried both RAR opener and a Zip Extractor that supposedly opens both zip and rar files but neither worked for me. Anything else you suggest?

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks a million! It worked!